# Atomic Batch Insert / Update in Jooq

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a program that monitors services and saves their current status. At regular intervals, my program checks in with each service and stores information about them in postgres. Most of the time, this involves updating existing rows in the database. But some times, new services will need to be added as well.

I am storing them with a schema that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE services IF NOT EXISTS (
  id          SERIAL    NOT NULL,
  name        TEXT      NOT NULL,
  status      TEXT    ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
)
```

Where the ID specifies a machine, and the name specifies one service on that machine. The POJO is pretty simple:

```
public class Service {
  int id;
  String name;
  String status;
}
```

For example, my table may start with only one row: `(22, "api", "active")`. At a scheduled interval, my program determines that there are now 2 services running on one machine, and that the current service's status has changed:

- (22, "api", "error")
- (22, "messaging", "active")

My method looks like this:

```
  Set<ServicesRecord> records = listServices
    .stream()
    .map(service -> {
      ServicesRecord record = new ServicesRecord();
      record.setId(service.id);
      record.setName(service.name);
      record.setStatus(service.status);
      return record;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(this.configuration);
    dsl.batchStore(records).execute();
}
```

However, this gives me an error when I try to run it:

```
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "foobar"."services" ("id", "name", "status", values (?, ?, ?)]; Batch entry 0 insert into "foobar"."services" ("id", "name", "status") values (1, 'testName', 'baz') was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "services_pkey"
```

I can see `batchStore` fails because it uses `UpdatableRecord`'s `store` method, which in turn fails because I am creating a new record instead of getting one from jooq.

I am considering an alternative approach like this:

1. Fetch all the records from the database.
2. For each record that matches `records`, I set `changed` to `true`.
3. Then I run `batchStore`

Alternatively, I could do this?

1. Fetch all the records from the database.
2. Make a list of records to be inserted and use `batchInsert`
3. Make a list of records to be updated, modify their records, and use `batchStore`

But both of these run the risk of not being atomic. If the database changes while I am on step 2, my uses of `batchStore` can still fail. What I would like is a way to do this kind of batch storage in a single operation, instead of doing a fetch followed by an execute. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`batchMerge()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchMerge(org.jooq.UpdatableRecord...)), which will ship with jOOQ 3.14: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10046

Alternatively, you can use the [data import API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-sources/importing-source-records/). You can then combine the [`onDuplicateKeyUpdate()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-options/import-option-duplicates/) clause with appropriate [batch sizes](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-options/importing-option-throttling/).

Or, you can write explicit [`INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/) and [batch them explicitly](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/).

Answer (score 0):

Example [batchMerge()](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchMerge(org.jooq.UpdatableRecord...)) for JOOQ 3.17

```
List<UpdatableRecord<ServiceRecord>> list = new ArrayList<>();
UpdatableRecord<ServiceRecord> record1 = new UpdatableRecordImpl<>(SERVICE);
record1.setValue(SERVICE.ID, 1);
record1.setValue(SERVICE.NAME, "1");
record1.setValue(SERVICE.STATUS, "1");
list.add(record1);
...
list.add(recordN);
dsl.batchMerge(list).execute();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).